# Adding cron job?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, vps

I need to add a cron task that is supposed to run every 10 minutes.

This is the code I was given by the developers of my software:

```
/usr/bin/wget --delete-after https://example.com/starter.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I logged into the crontab using the crontab -e command and there I added to code like this:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget --delete-after https://example.com/starter.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Something seems to be wrong because my software is still warning me that the cronjob is not set.

What am I doing wrong?

My vps is on Ubuntu on DigitalOcean.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Your crontab does not run every 10 minutes but runs every hour on the 10th minute. replace 10 by `*/10`. Have a look at [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_*_*_*_*)